# How to make MongoDB connection string with python that has read only

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, connection-string, pymongo-3.x

the mongodb connection string for python  looks like this

**mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.zev7c.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority**

with this connection string, I can create a database and delete a database and I can update the documents in collections and read the documents, I can do each and every operation with full control.

**document= {"studentid" : 1, "studentName" : "Rajkumar", "Branch" : "Mechanical", "joinedyear" : 2016, "Hostel" : "A1"}
x=collec.insert_one(document)**

if I write the above command in python , I can insert the data into collection.

my Requirement is: I need to make the above connection string for READ only acces.
if someone gives that connection string to me, when i try to delete any DB/collection/documents, it should not work.

so, how to make that connection string for READ ONLY ACCESS. neither create nor delte or update

Comment: Create a user that only has read access to the database in question.

Comment: @rdas how to create a user has read access to the database?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/